# Modifying querystring of prepared statement with PDO

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

I'm extending the PDO class to add functions that manipulate the querystring of a prepared statement. For example make a query searchable or add pagination.

For example:

```
$documents_query = $DB->prepare( "SELECT id, title, file_name, datetime_added
                                    FROM documents
                                    ORDER BY datetime_added DESC" );

$documents_query->paginate( $page_number, RESULTS_PER_PAGE );
```

The question is how to modify the querystring (which is readonly) and save it, so it can get executed later on?

This is an example of how my extended PDOStatement class looks like:

```
class CustomStatement extends PDOStatement
{
    public function paginate( $current_page, $max_results )
    {
        // Add SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS so we can count the total amount of results
        $select_index = stripos( $this->queryString, 'SELECT' );

        $statement = substr_replace( $this->queryString, 'SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS', $select_index, 6 );

        // Add LIMIT to the end of the query
        $start_limit = ( $current_page - 1 ) * $max_results;

        $statement = $statement . ' LIMIT ' . $start_limit . ', ' . $max_results;

        // What to do here?
        return $this->prepare( $statement );
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `paginate` your new `prepare`?

Comment: That's not intended. You need to create a new prepared statement handle, if you want to execute a different query.

Comment: I think, perhaps, you don't understand prepared statements. The prepared statement is sent to the server which keeps it, waiting for data to insert and execute on. Once its prepared, the mySQL server has it -- you can no longer do anything with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know, I generally find that extending PDOStatement is not your best option. At a minimum, subclassing `PDOStatement` means you need to subclass `PDO`. It gets messy. There also isn't really terribly much benefit in doing that -- you can't modify the original query, PDOStatement can't really be modified.

It is better, in my experience to write a wrapper around PDO which will allow you to manipulate the contents. This will let you manipulate the strings *before* they get to the point where you want to paginate. This also happens to be the way that most frameworks will use PDO.

Answer (score 2):

Once a statement has been prepared, you cannot modify it.  If you want to modify it prior to preparing it, take the query string, edit what you want through it, and then prepare your statement.